# Connection to WiFi when it shows up - DHCP timeout?

Tags: wifi, connection, dhcp

We switch off WiFi an a raspberry over night. In the morning both is switched on together. Unfortunately the pi starts faster than the access point and therefore the pi could not connect to a wifi. When the pi is started manually later, when the AP is up and running, it connects to the given wifi.
Is there a way that the pi checks if there is a wifi available when he is not connected?

Thanks for your help.

Regards
Martin

Comment: Martin - have you tried the answer below? Did it work? Feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that your DHCP client (`dhcpcd`) has *"given up"* before your WiFi network begins responding. I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Postpone the `dhcpcd` startup, or
2. Tell `dhcpcd` to try longer.

#### 1. Postpone `dhcpcd` startup:

You might try this... I've tried it on my system; it didn't break anything, and did seem to delay the boot process:

Edit the file `/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service` - for *example*:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service
```

Add the following line in the `[Service]` section: `ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60`. Insert it just before the `ExecStart=` line as shown below:

> [Service]
> Type=forking
> PIDFile=/run/dhcpcd.pid
> ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60
> ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b
> ExecStop=/sbin/dhcpcd -x

I'm not well-versed in `systemd`, but this one-line addition to `/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service` may give your WiFi enough of a head start to resolve your issue. I'm sure there's a more *elegant* solution - I'll post an ***edit*** if I find it, but try this in the meantime & let us know how it worked.

#### 2. Tell `dhcpcd` to try longer (EDIT):

Here's an option that ***should*** work - I like this one better than the original answer because:

**a.** it seems *less kludge-y* than the `systemd` service file modification above, and

**b.** Roy Marples (the `dhcpcd` author) is on record confirming the `timeout` option causes `dhcpcd` to persist in its quest for an IP address *indefinitely*.

***Here's how:***

1. Open `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` with your favorite editor - for example:

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

2. Insert the following line somewhere near the end of the file:

```
timeout 0
```

3. `reboot` or re-start `dhcpcd`:

```
sudo reboot 

## OR ##

sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

As before, your feedback is requested.